# Notification function not working after sending the message

Tags: android, firebase, notifications, android-notifications

I was trying to implement notification functionality in my chat application but was unable to send Notification to the receiver. Its getting failed.

Successfully able to create token in the Firebase.

```
 private void sendNotification(String receiver, String username, String message){
    DatabaseReference tokens = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Tokens");
    Query query = tokens.orderByKey().equalTo(receiver);
    query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()){
                Token token = dataSnapshot.getValue(Token.class);
                Data data = new Data(fAuth.getUid(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher, username +": "+message, "New Message", SenderUID);

                Sender sender = new Sender(data, token.getToken());

                apiServices.sendNotification(sender)
                        .enqueue(new Callback<MyResponse>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(Call<MyResponse> call, Response<MyResponse> response) {
                                if (response.code() == 200){
                                    if (response.body().success != 1){
                                        Toast.makeText(UserChatActivity.this, "Failed!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(Call<MyResponse> call, Throwable t) {

                            }
                        });
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: "It's getting failed" doesn't provide enough information so we can help. What exactly doesn't work? Do you have any errors?

Comment: @AlexMamo After sending the message to the receiver. The receiver is not gettting message notification. But the sender is getting toast message "Failed!!".
if (response.body().success != 1)